# "Muita pouca gente" or/ou "muito pouca gente"?

Tags: gênero, concordância-nominal

Which one is correct? Is it correct to use "muito" in the feminine? Does it follow the gender of the following substantive?

---

Qual das duas seria a forma correta? É correto usar "muito" na forma feminina? Segue a forma do substantivo seguinte?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, when *muito* is an adverb like in this case, you don’t make *muito* agree with the word it modifies, so *muit**o** pouca gente*.  Only when it’s an adjective does it agree with its noun — so for example, *muit**as** amigas*.

---

From [Concordância Nominal (noun agreement) at www.portuguese.com.br](http://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/concordancia-nominal-.html):

> 4- Muito, pouco, caro, barato, longe, meio, sério, alto
>
> São palavras que variam seu comportamento, funcionando ora como advérbios (sendo assim invariáveis), ora como adjetivos (variáveis).

That is,

> > These are words that vary their behavior, acting sometimes as adverbs (being therefore invariable), sometimes as adjectives (variable).

---

Não, quando *muito* é advérbio como neste caso, não é variado para combinar com a palavra que modifica, assim *muit**o** pouca gente*. Só quando ele é adjetivo faz concordar com o seu substantivo; por exemplo, *muit**as** amigas*.

Comment: Adverb? But where is the verb?

Comment: @bfavaretto Adverbs do not have to apply to only verbs alone. They can also apply to other modifiers, so to adjectives and other adverbs. That’s what’s happening here: in *muito pouca gente*, the word *pouca* is an adjective that matches number and gender of *gente*. But *muito* here means “very” not “much”, and so it is an adverb that applies to the adjective *pouca*. Since it is here an adverb, this time it is invariable.

Comment: You're right, I seem to have forgotten about this fact a long time ago :(

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case,**"muito" is an adverb, and adverbs never vary in gender or number.**

Comment: Hey, didn’t I say that already? :)  Welcome to Portuguese.SE!

Comment: @tchrist Although the question was already answered, it's good to have another answer that reinforces it, so that it's sure that the answer to the question is really such. Also, remember that currently we need more answers per questions (not that we need to just repeat answers, but try to complement in some way, if possible).

Comment: @BrunoLopes Agreed. We would like a better answer-to-question ratio.

Comment: @tchrist  Yes, you did say that  and much more.  My bad.  Then again, I simplified it in 16 words. :-)